# Identifying the relationship between $S_n , \frac{n}{(n+\sqrt n)}$

Tags: calculus

Had this question pop up in a textbook and kinda got somewhere but nowhere at the same time!

Using the summation principle i managed to calc that $S_n = 1-\frac{1}{(n+1)}$ for $\frac{1}{(n+1)}$ but couldn't solve for the other one let alone relate them or create an inequality.

Kind gave up and wrote: $\frac{1}{(n+1)} < S_n < \frac{n}{(n+1)}$ $\rightarrow$ mainly with the justification that as the value on the denominator increases the value of the fraction becomes smaller and closer to 0

Any help please?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is the definition of $S_n$ in title ?